# why is the command display=:0.0 going off?

Tags: bash

The following command : display=:0.0 in bash script is used. Then when calling export, I can see it's there.

However, after a while, this command is no more in the export list and I have to do it again.

**Note**
There is only 1 session running and I'm doing nothing on the command line. There may be a program running in background.
This is a ssh session (putty).

What could be causing this?

Comment: In a single shell session? Something setting the value to something else and/or using `unset` on it. In a different shell session? That's expected, that's a per-session variable/export.

Comment: in a single shell session, yes I tried staying here waiting and it goes off

Comment: It's not a command, it's just a parameter assignment. It's not clear what could be unsetting the value within the same shell session.

Comment: so if there would be a program running in background, it is the only thing which could change it?

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim, no, environment variables are process-specific.  One process cannot alter another's (i.e. your shell's) environment.  If `display` is being unset, then that's happening directly in the affected shell.  Clearly you are not doing that knowingly, but perhaps you have an alias defined that has that as one of its effects.

Comment: but if I'm not inputting something and I wait for tree hours, it's sometimes off. I don't input alias or anything meanwhile

Comment: There's no way that without you doing anything or any scripts/functions running in that shell session that the exported variable/value would go away. It just isn't. When you say it "is no more in the export list" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: when I do export, I don't see the 0.0 anymore

Comment: We'd need to see the script, or enough of the script to reproduce the issue. It's possible that you're setting the variable inside a subshell (subshells are often created implicitly without intent, for instance if you're piping to a loop), and that the subshell exits later in your script. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for an example of how setting an environment variable in the wrong place can cause it to disappear before this is expected.

Comment: If you can build a reproducer that complies with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, this will make it much easier to answer this question; right now, there's not enough information to operate from.

Comment: thanks a lot for all! Actually I found out the problem, I was logging through ssh, and it sometimes logged off then in again without my noticing. I will set this as the answer. I realise I should've mention I was through ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was logged with ssh. I realised I sometime got logged off and on automatically. Then the export command would be off because it's a "new" session. Cannot explain why this happen with putty though.